# Where do I place a file for bookmarks for all users

Tags: bookmarks, firefox

With previous versions of Firefox I put my bookmarks.html file in /etc/firefox/profile and all new user accounts got automatically these bookmarks.

This folder doesn't exist on ubuntu 11.04; I tried to create it and put the bookmarks.html file in it but it doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, the default bookmarks are hidden in */usr/lib/firefox-n.n/omni.jar*, you can modify this file to change default bookmarks for all users. Anyway this is not a good practise and I hope providing defaults will get easier in time.

A nicer way is to provide something in a default profile directory in order to let migration assistant do importing the bookmarks, when new Firefox profile is created. I think you have to provide *profiles.ini* in */etc/skel/.mozilla/firefox*.

```
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1

[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=5ge4y5n2.default
Default=1
```

And under */etc/skel/.mozilla/firefox/5ge4y5n2.default* you can provide your files to be imported to a new profile, for example *bookmarks.html* or *places.sqlite*.

Only problem with this practise is that it allows only one Firefox profile per user and deleting the profile and creating new one loses the defaults.

Answer (score 2):

Create `/usr/lib/firefox/defaults/profile` directory and put a customized `bookmarks.html` file inside.

It works on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Does not work on ubuntu 13

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use one profile as a regular one, and the other profile folders as symbolic links to the actual profile.

Comment: How could I do that exactly?

Comment: cd to the user dir where you want this to happen and then rm the bookmarksfile. You then make a symlink (ln -s /{dir}/{correct_bookmarksfile} {bookmarksfile}). You can even automate this by altering /etc/profile (that one gets fired when you create a new user)